# what does #pragma acc host_data do?

Tags: openacc

What does the construction (p is on gpu)

```
#pragma acc host_data use_device(p)
{...}
```

exactly do? 
"A host_data construct makes the address of device data available
on the host." (*The OpenAcc API*). use_device - "directs the compiler to use the device address of any entry in list, for instance, when passing a variable to procedure" (*OpenAcc Programming and best practices Guide*). Does it mean that, for example, if i have the variables

```
int A=1;
int B=2;
#pragma acc declare device_resident(A,B)
...
```

alocated on the device, i can write from the host

```
#pragma acc host_data use_device(A,B)
{ 
  memcpy(&A,&B,sizeof(int));
}
```

i suppose this is wrong. Please, explain this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenACC "host_data" directive is used when you need to get the device address for a variable for use within host code.  It's mostly used for interoperability with CUDA or CUDA aware MPI when you want to pass in the device address of a variable.

In your example, this would most likely cause an error since passing a device address to the system "memcpy" would give a seg fault.  Though if you change "memcpy" to "cudaMemcpy" or other routine which expects a device address to be passed in, then it would be fine.

This blog post may be helpful:      https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/3-versatile-openacc-interoperability-techniques/